# Input elements differ from output elements from files C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I have been having some problems with my code. I was asked to input elements from an .dat file into an array. For class we have to do this for various files without knowing how many elements will be in each file. The only thing we know is that here will never be more then 5000 elements per file.

One of my input file has the following elements:

```
5.675207 -0.571210
0.728926 0.666069
2.290909 0.751731 2.004545 0.907396
0.702893 0.646427 5.909504 -0.365045
2.082645 0.871841 5.597107 -0.633507
6.117769 -0.164663 6.091736 -0.190282
5.571074 -0.653433 4.503719 -0.978307
3.983058 -0.745620
3.670661 -0.504729
5.857438 -0.413001
```

When I run my code:

```
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

if (argc < 3)
{
    cout << "Incorrect usage:  prog.exe filenname number" << endl;
    cout << "Exiting now, please try again." << endl;
    return -1;
}

fin.open(argv[1]);
if (!fin)
{
    cout << "Error opening file \"" << argv[1] << "\", exiting." << endl;
    return -1;
}

fout.open(argv[2]); 

int count = 0;
int word; 
double points[5000]; 

while (fin >> word) 
{
    fin >> points[count]; 
    ++count; 
}

fout << "Numer of points is: " << count/2 << endl; 

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    fout << points[i] << " "; 
}

fin.close();
fout.close(); 

return 0;
}
```

I outputted the elements just to make sure that they were properly inputted. I get the following and I don't know why.

```
0.675207 0.57121 
0.728926 0.666069 
0.290909 0.751731 0.004545 0.907396 
0.702893 0.646427 0.909504 0.365045 
0.082645 0.871841 0.597107 0.633507 
0.117769 0.164663 0.091736 0.190282 
0.571074 0.653433 0.503719 0.978307 
0.983058 0.74562 
0.670661 0.504729
0.857438 0.413001
```

The first digit is converted to a 0 for some reason and the negative ones become positive. Would anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: You should learn how to use the debugger and step through the code.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You're reading the items from the stream twice (alternating into `word` and `points[count]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int word;
```

is doing you no favours. First it's an integer so `fin >> word` only reads the integer portion of the inputs. 5.675207 is read as 5. the .675207 is left in the file stream for `fin >> points[count]`. Words isn't stored anywhere to the 5 is discarded but the .675207 lives on as 0.675207 in `points[0]`.

Where the negative signs are going I didn't bother trying to figure out because

```
while (fin >> points[count])
{
    ++count;
}
```

fixes everything.

Answer (score 0):

When you read in the numbers from the the file you are extracting them as "word" and then storing them as "points".  "word" is an integer and "points" is a double, this will give you unexpected behavior.  The compiler should give you warnings about this.

Comment: should also point out that he's reading twice from `fin` which is hardly ever what he wanted

Comment: I changed 'word' into a double but I got every other element into my file. It also kept changing the first number before the decimal into a 0